# Repeated measures Lmer and random terms interaction

Tags: repeated-measures, interaction, lme4-nlme

I am having some issues in defining a syntax for a repeated measure log regression using the `lmer()` function from the `lme4` package.  Some of you were really helpful when I first posted my doubts.  However, after reading your answers and some of the links that you kindly posted, I am still struggling. I have 62 participants, each participant sees 120 trials, so the same trial is seen by all 62 (only once).  In each trial, participants have to report either 1 (yes) or 0 (no).  I am interested in the effect of trial as well as subject since I know that most participants (not everyone) tend to say more Yes more often as the number of trials increases (i.e., towards the end of the experiment). I was first recommended to model like this:

```
model<-glmer(DV~X+Y+Z+Y:Z + (1|Subject), data=data)
```

But this, to my knowledge, only captures the random effect of `Subject`.  How do I control for `Trial`?  Should I define an interaction effect between `Subject` and `Trial`?

I thought about the following model:

```
model<-glmer(DV~X+Y+Z+Y:Z + (1|Subject:Trial_Order), data=data)
```